# How Can I Share Document Files with Multiple Web Projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have three ASP.NET MVC Projects. before I use one single Directory to manage documents/files, and all projects can access from that source, but now I have to store files in particular projects (under App_Data) and have to access from other projects.
My question is, how can I manage this?

Answer (score 1):

Linking files in Visual Studio could perhaps be a solution to your problem.

https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2019/07/linking-files-in-visual-studio.html

I used it myself the other day where I needed a single .csv file available in multiple projects.

Comment: No bro, I need only Access documents files, such as Image, xls etc, not code file,

Comment: Maybe I was not 100% clear in my answer, but the file that I was using was a .csv file.